# How to configure GitHub webhook URL in Red Hat OpenShift?

Tags: github, openshift, webhooks, openshift-client-tools, github-webhook

I am not getting the GitHub webhook URL after creating a new project on OpenShift. I have checked the build configuration as well, but it wasn't there.

[image]

Comment: A new openshift project aka namespace does not create a GitHub webhook. Did you mean to have a URL that triggers a build in openshift whenever your GitHub repo changes?

Comment: Yes. How can I configure that?

Comment: I followed a video tutorial from OpenShift on deploying a Web Application using OpenShift and followed all the steps but couldn't find the GitHub webhook URL

Comment: Use `oc set triggers bc/webapp --from-github`, changing `webapp` to your `bc` name. This will create a GitHub web hook entry. Then query the `bc` to find out what token is assigned.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried that too, but it didn't work. Please see my question, I have added the screenshot of it.

Comment: @ShashankkShekarChaturvedi you are not supposed to run oc there. Download oc to your local machine